# Calculating Angle/Rate of Climb of a Line in Spotfire and Excel

Tags: excel, calculated-columns, spotfire

I am looking to calculate the angle of climb / slope of multiple lines in Spotfire (calculated columns) as well as Excel.

On the graph (attached) I would like to be able to color the lines by their continuous angle of climb / slope values. I.e., where the angle of climb is steep it is one color, where the curves have shallower climbs, there is another color.

How would I calculated these as values (per location) as a calculated column in Spotfire, and in Excel?

Here are the values that were use to make the graph.

Location,Var X,Var Y

A,0,0

A,0.02,0.08

A,0.08,0.16

A,0.2,0.21

A,0.25,0.28

A,0.34,0.35

A,0.421,0.42

A,0.502,0.83

A,0.583,0.86

A,0.664,0.89

A,0.745,0.92

A,0.826,0.95

A,1,1

B,0,0

B,0.13,0.08

B,0.29,0.16

B,0.31,0.21

B,0.35,0.28

B,0.42,0.35

B,0.43,0.42

B,0.59,0.49

B,0.63,0.56

B,0.7,0.58

B,0.78,0.62

B,0.85,0.65

B,1,1

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can post the data as plain text? You can use [this site](https://justpaste.it/) as well if you want. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For slope, your calculation would be:

- Insert a column to number the rows: `Rank(RowId(),"asc",[Location]) as [RowNumber]`
- Calculate slope: `([VarY] - Min([VarY]) OVER (Previous([RowNumber]))) / ([VarX] - Min([VarX]) OVER (Previous([RowNumber])))`

Here, the slope will be based off the current and previous row.

[image]

Comment: @scscimon - sorry I didn't get the text data to you sooner!

Comment: No worries @Lgeo I just wanted to avoid a type-o

Comment: @sccimon, testing it now!

Comment: @Lgeo You can also use Next instead of previous if you'd like to calculate it from one point to the next versus one point to the previous. The math is simple, and the slope calculation is correct, but what you do with it could be tricky.

Comment: sorry for posting late (traveling)...looks like it works great, thanks!